# How to remove duplicates from a list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates from this list:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> val = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

It does not work if I apply Distinct() in this way:

```
 List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = val.Distinct().ToList<Dictionary<string, object>>()
```

Update: Problem is now solved. I used the MySQL union command to read table from the database.

Comment: Did you ask this exact question already? I can't find it anymore, but I'm sure I saw it not that long ago... the problem with that question still exists with this one: how do you define "duplicate"? Exact same instance, same keys, same keys *and* values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = val.Distinct(new myDictionaryComparer()).ToList();
```

where `myDictionaryComparer` is a [Comparer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=VS.100).aspx). You can implement your comparison logic in this class.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to wrap your dictionary in MyClass. You can simply define a class implementing IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, object>> and pass it to Distinct

Comment: @digEmAll: Yes! what you say is more relevant in this scenario. Thanks. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```
val.Distinct()
```

Comment: Are the repeated items the same instance?