# How to remove non-duplicates from a list in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to do the opposite thing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756458/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-c)

I have a list and I know how to remove the duplicates. But I want to have an option where the user can select which duplicate to keep. Some query quere I can have a list that will only show the duplicates. Something like:

Lets say my list is:

> "tom" "bob" "Frank" "bob" "Lacey" "Frank"

I know that if I use the distinct method I will get:

> "tom" "bob" "Frank" "Lacey"

I don't know what method to I have to use to get:

> "bob" "bob" "frank" "frank"

or to get

> "bob" "frank"

cause those are the ones that repeat.

Comment: Group by Name having count > 1

Comment: In other words I want to do the same thing that iTunes does when you click on the option that says show duplicate songs.

Comment: @Joe: your answer match perfectly question asked. Why don't you post it as an answer to allow the OP to approve it?

Comment: @Sylverdrag I do not know LINQ well enough to provide an adequate answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to filter out the items that only occur once, then flatten the remaining items back into a list:

```
var resultList = list.GroupBy(x => x)
                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                     .SelectMany(g => g)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Also, slightly more efficient for the general case of an IEnumerable when having a large number of duplicates you could use `.Where( g=> g.Skip(1).Any())` instead of the above `Where` condition.

Comment: Why do we need SelectMany after Where condition? I am new to Linq please help me out in understanding this.

Comment: @Sandeep: SelectMany "flattens" a list of lists to a single lists that consists of all the elements contained in the original lists

Answer (score 1):

I needed to compare them by a specific property theretofore I just modified your query BrokenGlass to

```
var resultList = itemsThatNeedToBeAdded.GroupBy(x => x.property1)
                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1 )
                     .SelectMany(g => g)
                     .ToList();
```